# IE Not using redirected URL for resolving relative URLs

Tags: css, internet-explorer, url, servlets

I have a servlet that generates CSS for a given colorScheme name if it exists in the database. However, should the colorScheme not be found, it issues a response.sendRedirect() to the location of the actual file on our CDN.

This works in all browsers except for IE when the CSS contains relative links to images for icons, backgrounds, etc. Every other browser uses the redirected URL (CDN url) to resolve the relative URLs in the CSS file, but IE still uses the original request URL (servlet URL).

I can't change the relative URLs to absolute URLs in the CSS files for a number of reasons I can't go in to. Is there a way to get IE to use the redirected URL instead of the request URL for the relative URL resolution?

Comment: Wow, that's insane. A shoot in the dark, try 301 redirect instead of (default) 302. Anything else can't be controlled from the server side, I am afraid. You'd likely need to resort to generate the necessary `<link>` with the right URL programmatically during rendering of the view.

Comment: Why not put the cdn url in the html. This way you don't have the overhead of an extra http request with a 302. You use a CDN for speed, so don't slow things down first, or it will be fairly pointless to use a CDN.

Comment: I tried a 301 as well to no effect. Unfortunately the calls to this servlet are coming from a JS "widget" that doesn't know beforehand whether the CSS exists (colorscheme is a passed in parameter to this "widget"). I will probably resort to using something like jQuery's getScript to attempt a load from servlet with an error handler function to load the CSS from the CDN if servlet doesn't find the CSS and remove the redirect.

Comment: Nuts! Is this all versions of IE or just one specific version?

Comment: Could you include a snippet of your code that would allow us to reproduce the problem? Otherwise it is somewhat difficult to test whether a proposed solution works or not.

Comment: As far as I know it is all versions of IE, 8 or below. I did not test 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are processing our HTML/JS in another servlet before the call to the colorScheme servlet, what I did was check to see if the requested skin was dynamic (from the servlet) or not at this stage. If the colorScheme  is dynamic, I write out the link tag with the address of the CSS servlet, otherwise I write out the address of the CDN.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like more of a code design problem. Personally I don't rely on IE to do anything as it should. It always lets me down :(. I would always include your CSS from the CDN at the begining of the head using the HTML LINK tag, then let the JS import overwrite it afterword. This way your website will also look decent in noscript browsers.

Comment: +1 for "Personally I don't rely on IE to do anything as it should"

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use css @import tag instead of redirecting to the external css file.

```
@import url('http://www.example.org/style.css');
```